# Extension operators for topological vector space-valued smooth functions on closed sets

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

There are many known results about extension theorems for real-valued functions on closed sets, with varying levels of differentiability and so on, all very roughly following the Whitney approach. For smooth functions one has the theorem of Mitjagin-Seely that the restriction map $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \to C^\infty([0,1])$ between Fréchet spaces has a section. Wockel extended (no pun intended) the *surjectivity* of this map to the case of functions valued in a general Fréchet space (Corollary 19, [Smooth Extensions and Spaces of Smooth and Holomorphic Mappings](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511064v1), arXiv:math/0511064). He also shows the map $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,F) \to C^\infty([0,1]^n,F)$ to be surjective.

However I've not seen a discussion of extension *operators* in such a setting: functions on closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued in Fréchet spaces. More generally, one could ask for an extension theorem for smooth functions (or other levels of differentiability) for topological vector spaces, and conditions for the existence of extension operators. In the Fréchet setting one can try to use the splitting theory using properties ($\Omega$) and (DN) (see for example [these lectures of Vogt](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~vogt/manu/N_03b.pdf)), and so one could try to prove these properties for the relevant spaces of functions.

Has anyone seen this before?

**Edit** To clarify, an *extension operator* is a continuous linear section of a restriction map between function spaces (or more accurately, from a function space to a space of Whitney jets, when appropriate), in the case that the restriction map is surjective. Wockel's theorem says that we have surjectivity, so one needs either an explicit construction (as in Mitjagin-Seeley) that works for 'nice' cases, or an appeal to a general splitting theorem (as in Vogt, used by Frerick for rather nasty corkscrew-type sets).

Perhaps an easier question is whether the usual operators that work for, say, closed sets with smooth boundaries have exact analogues when dealing with (complete lctvs)-valued functions.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "extension operator". As written, it's not clear to me that you are asking for something that's different from Wockel's result.

Comment: The difference between surjections and _continuously split_ surjections of tvs...

Comment: Ah, I see. You want a linear(?) operator that will give you an actual extension for any data given on the closed set alone.

Comment: In you have an extension operator for the scalar functions you ca tensorize it with the identity on the Frechet space. Doesn't this give an extension operator for the Frechet valued functions?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth does this work for Whitney jets?? Also, I'm not sure about how the tensor products work. The reason I'm asking is that I know there are subtleties, and need some reference or other good reason to not worry about them.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth and section 6.1 of these notes: http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~vogt/vorlesungen/fs.pdf make me worry a little if I'm going to get all the smooth Fréchet-space-valued functions by tensoring the scalar-valued function space with the Fréchet space.